# Hausdorff distance restricted to linear subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space, $Q \subset V$ be convex and compact and $Q_n \subset V$ be convex and compact for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $Q_n \rightarrow Q$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$ in Hausdorff distance.

Let $L$ be a linear subspace of $V$ with $Q_n \cap L \neq \emptyset$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $Q \cap L \neq \emptyset$.

Does it then also hold that $Q_n \cap L \rightarrow Q \cap L$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$ in Hausdorff distance?

I would also be thankful for any pointers to relevant literature.

Comment: This already fails in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Let $Q$ be the line segment joining $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and let $Q_n$ be the line segment joining $(0,1/n)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: @NikWeaver That was simpler than expected, thanks!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.

Comment: For compact convex sets, I think Nik Weaver's example is typical, that is for any such sequence $Q_n$ in an  infinite dimensional  $V$, there exists a subspace $L$ for which the intersection is not continuous.
If the $Q_n$ are non-empty, closed, "equi-uniformly  convex" sets (hence they are not compact, unless $V$ is finite dimensional), then I guess the continuity of intersection with $L$ is true; maybe also with any closed convex $L$.